# Is every function with a jump discontinuity weakly differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

Let $\Omega$ be a Lebesgue measurable subset of $ \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Recall that a locally integrable function  $f:\Omega
\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is weakly differentiable on $\Omega$ if there exists a locally integrable function $g$ such that

$$\int_{\Omega}f\partial^{\alpha}\phi=(-1)^{|\alpha|}\int_{\Omega}
g \phi$$
for every $\phi \in C^{\infty}_{c}(\Omega)$. Here $\alpha$ is a multi-index and $g$ is called the $\alpha^{\text{th}}$ weak partial derivative of $f$.

A typical example for weakly differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$
are continuous functions that are differentiable almost everywhere like $x\mapsto |x|$ or functions with corners in general.

Also, typical examples for functions not weakly differentiable functions on $\mathbb{R}$ are functions with a jump discontinuity.

My intuition is that every function on the real line with a jump discontinuity is not weakly differentiable.

Is this true ?

What is the picture like in higher dimensions ?
Precisely:
   Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, $n\geq 2$, is continuous on $\mathbb{R}^{n}\setminus \{x_{0}\}$ such that $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)$ exists and $f(x_{0})$ exists as well, but $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_{0}}f(x)\neq f(x_0)$. Is $f$ not weakly differentiable ?
More interestingly, what happens when $f$ is bounded at some point but not continuous thereat?

A hint for a proof would be really appreciated.

Comment: I'm confused, isn't the line "Also, typical examples..." exactly saying that you can prove the claim in the line "My intuition is that..."? Also, your second last paragraph: your $f$ is almost everywhere equal to a $C^0(\mathbb R^n)$ function. Since weak derivatives are only defined a.e. we can just ssume its $C^0$. Are such functions weakly diff? No, and you already have issues in $n=1$: check the devil's staircase

Comment: What you mean is that there does not exist a continuous representative of your function $f$ - otherwise we could just take the zero function $f=0$, change it on the set of zero measure $\{x_{0}\}$ to make it discontinuous and you have your example

Comment: @Calvin Khor. Thanks for your comment. The examples show that there exist bounded functions continuous almost everywhere that are not weakly differentiable. These examples do not imply that EVERY such function is not weakly differentiable.

Comment: @MF14. Thanks for your comment. My question is can we prove  that every function on the real line with a jump discontinuity is automatically not weakly  differentiable. What is the analogue in higher dimensions?

Comment: @Medo that’s not what it says since Eg sin(1/x) Is bounded and continuous almost everywhere but has an essential singularity. And thinking about it almost everywhere is not so useful as in MF’s comment. Somehow it is the a.e. Equivalence to a clean example that is important. But I get your point. At the same time I think the moment you formulate it as a precise statement about functions with finitely many jump discontinuities in R^n that are otherwise smooth it follows by the simplest example (Sgn) and linearity of the weak derivative

Comment: The previous comment was meant for $\mathbb R^1$, was typed on a phone, sorry. There isn't an obvious analogue of jump discontinuities in higher dimension, unless you count "jumping along a line" or a hypersurface, because "jumping" needs you to go from "left to right"

Comment: @ Calvin Khor. Thanks a lot for the interesting and useful comments. I will think about it a bit more before I reply.

Comment: @Calvin Khor,MF14.  Now I think my question is naive and I get your comments. Of course, all functions on the real line with a jump discontinuity will look "the same" in a neighborhood of the jump. And in higher dimenstions we construct an example via the tensor product of a one dimensional function with a jump with a smooth function in the remaining variable.

Comment: Medo indeed, furthermore in dimension 1 it occurred to me that it’s much easier to describe the functions that are weakly differentiable than the ones that aren’t, but I don’t have time to write a full answer. The weakly diff functions in 1D are precisely those which are locally in $W^{1,1}$, and these are characterised as the set of locally absolutely continuous functions. This immediately rules out all kinds of discontinuities, as well as the less subtle issues like the singular continuous function (devil’s staircase) above. I haven’t written this as an answer as I’m not sure how to ...

Comment: ... source these. I know there’s a proof in Evans if you look in the time varying Banach space valued functions and use the fact that R is a Banach space.... but that’s a little roundabout and he refers to an earlier part of the chapter. You might also try Leoni’s book, a first course in Sobolev spaces

Comment: @ Calvin Khor. Thanks a lot. Very useful comments..